# Is it possible to not decrease the quality of audio from other apps while also listening?

Tags: react-native, agora.io

I am trying to build a clubhouse clone and currently I am using agora for the audio realted things. I was wondering if it is possible to not decrease the quality of audio from other apps while also listening like clubhouse.

I tried using
`engine.enableLocalAudio(false);`

but listening to music or other volume still decreases the sound quality and the volume of the audio. Anyone have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio feature is "ducking". It's hard to look for unless you know that keyword!

This answer on a similar question seems to do what you're looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62840934/2156765